# How can I get the height of auto-grown text box before Print event in an MS Access 2016 Report?

Tags: ms-access, textbox, report, ms-access-2016, expandable

I want to get the final height of a multi-line text box in an Access report so that I can align vertically smaller, one-line boxes, to that expanded one.

[image: Expanded textboxes with top-aligned one-line textboxes]

So that they end up looking like this:

[image: Expanded textboxes with vertically centered one-line textboxes]

It seems the only way to know the expanded size is in the *Print* event, and it's too late there because one can't move already drawn boxes. And yes, I've tried the *Format* event, but there the height is the one given before growing, at design time.
Does anyone know of an alternative? Maybe an add-on textbox control with this capability? Or an add-on function to get the Textbox.Height just before the *Print* event occurs?